# Multiple CSS classes that change the same attributes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I keep seeing divs in our HTML pages with multiple (bootstrap) CSS classes that seem to do the same thing:
`<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9">`

Here's what dev tools show is being applied with the classes:
[image]

This happens all over the place, so as a sanity check, is there ever any reason for having multiple col-x classes? col-sm-9 is being overwritten, so it feels like a major oversight.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of reasons. Those are for the media queries. col-md-10 and col-sm-9 change the width of the element depending on screen size. They share many common attributes - such as padding and float.

Comment: @disinfor Ah that makes a lot of sense. TIL (finally) what media queries do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These classes define the width of columns based on how big the viewer's screen is. Sm is small or mobile screens, md is medium or tablet-sized screens, lg is large or desktop. While mobile, tablet and desktop are not universally defined screen sizes, the sm, md and lg cover these general areas. This page in Bootstraps documentation explains the grid system and gives you the official breakpoints of these screen sizes, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/.

Comment: I was reading some of my old questions, and didn't realize this (really obvious, in retrospect) one had an unaccepted answer. Better late than never ;)